# ServiceContractGenerator CollectionTypeMapping

Tags: .net, visual-studio, wcf

I'm using the class [ServiceContractGenerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicecontractgenerator(v=vs.110).aspx#Esempi) to "re-host" the Add-ServiceReference function of VisualStudio on an Application.

It works perfectly but I can't find where to set the following options in the ServiceContractGenerator:

[VisualStudio Add-ServiceReferenceOptions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awnJn.png)

Infact right now it maps Collections into array becasue it's the default selection, I want to let the user choose between the options as VS does.

Code snippet:

```
 Private Shared Function ImportWCFServiceReferenceDescription(url As String, Code As String, assemblyVersion As String) As ImportResult
    Dim result As ImportResult = New ImportResult() With {.Imported = False, .ErrorMessage = New StringBuilder(), .CompileUnit = New CodeCompileUnit()}
    If Not url.ToLower.EndsWith("?wsdl") AndAlso Not url.ToLower.EndsWith("?singlewsdl") Then url = url & "?wsdl"
    Dim mexClient As New MetadataExchangeClient(New Uri(url), MetadataExchangeClientMode.HttpGet)
    mexClient.ResolveMetadataReferences = True
    Dim metaDocs = mexClient.GetMetadata()
    Dim importer As New WsdlImporter(metaDocs)
    Dim generator As New ServiceContractGenerator()
    generator.NamespaceMappings.Add("*", String.Format("{0}.{1}", RootNamespace, Code))

    Dim contracts = importer.ImportAllContracts()
    importer.ImportAllEndpoints()
    For Each contract As ContractDescription In contracts
        generator.GenerateServiceContractType(contract)
    Next

    If generator.Errors.Count <> 0 Then
        result.ErrorMessage.AppendLine("No code generated")
        Return result
    End If
    result.CompileUnit = generator.TargetCompileUnit
    result.Imported = True
    Return result
End Function
```

Thanks

FT

Comment: Code helps! Include code snippets and it will be easier to help you..

Comment: Sure, edited the question. Thanks